# JavaScript how to attach result to api with array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Tell me how to properly make such a function. I use javascript with the React framework

i am get from API this json array

```
  [{
      id: 0,
      credit: {
        id: 7
      }
      "another data"
    }]
```

I want to have a result at the end, like this

```
[{
      id: 0,
      credit: {
        id: 7,
        bank: "Bank Name X" // This parameter must also be obtained from the API
      }
      "another data"
    }]
```

i am try attach with this function

```
let fData;
let lData = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  fData = {
    ...data[i],
    credit: {
      bank: axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/credits/" + data[i].credit.id)
        .then(function(result) {
          return result.data.partner.name;
        })
    }
  }
  lData.push(fData);
}

console.log(lData);
```

This code returns. How to get Bank Name X

```
credit:
bank: Promise
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: "Bank Name X"
```

Comment: Where and how do you use the returned data

Comment: next I show in render with map

Comment: And where are you fetching this data? In render method?

Comment: Can you please update the question with an example showing what you expect the end result to be?

Comment: variable data  i am get from API

Comment: @IncrediblePony y thank's for answear. i am updated post

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that in your React component when you want to fetch some data from API.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Bank extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/credits/`)
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({ data: res });
        })
    }

   render() {
       return (
         <ul>
          {this.state.data.map(d => <li>{d.credit.bank.name}</li>)}
        </ul>
      )
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This solution for me ) Thank's ru.stackoverflow

```
let fData;
let lData  = [];
let pData = [];


        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i ++){
            pdata.push(axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/credits/" + data[i].credit.id))
            fData = {
                ...data[i],
                credit: {
                  bank: "blank"

                }
            }
           lData.push(fData);
        }

Promise.all(pData).then(function(result){
    for(var res in result){
        lData[res].credit.bank = result[res].data.partner.name);
    }
    console.log(lData)
})
```